# Baking to Ambient Occlusion in Blender 2.71 has this distorted effect

Tags: ambient-occlusion

[image]

I just want the image baked to no distortion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to create a baked texture, I do this by having Bake Mode selected to Ambient Occlusion, with the UV map selected and the object selected, the image bakes like this. As you can see in this image, the baked result is not clean. Where the darker areas should be, it bakes into black and white noise instead of a smooth darker tone, which is what I'm trying to achieve.